# Selenium WebDriver for JavaScript w/ PhantomJS and driver.wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I wrote a little test case with `selenium-webdriver` and the JavaScript bindings with NodeJS and PhantomJS. It looks like this:

```
it("should upload a file", function(done) {
    driver.get('http://mysite.com/upload.php);
    driver.findElement({className:'subpagetitle'}).getText().then(function(text) {
        expect(text).to.equal('Client Document');
    });
    var file = Path.resolve('./dummyfile.txt');
    driver.findElement({sizzle:'input[type=file]'}).sendKeys(file);
    driver.wait(function() {
        console.log('waiting');
        return driver.isElementPresent({sizzle:"button:contains('Save')"});
    }, 10000);
    driver.saveScreenshot('screenshots/doc_upload.png').then(done);
    driver.findElement({sizzle:"button:contains('Save')"}).click();
});
```

When I run it with the PhantomJS webdriver it just hangs when it gets to the `driver.wait` command, and the `console.log` never gets printed.

It runs fine with the Chrome webdriver. Does `.wait` not work with PhantomJS or am I doing something wrong?